# How to get absolute path to a file packaged with the apk?

Tags: android, firebase, assets, firebase-storage

I am trying to make an app app that will be used to upload a file to the Firebase Storage. I don't want the user to have to choose a file instead  i want to package the file with the app. (e.g in the raw/asssets folder).

I have tried several things and I can't make sense of anything. I have no direction. I watched a few tutorials on youtube but all of them use 'choose a file' method.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the absolute the path of the file located in assets. Because those files which are located inside the assets folder does not have the absolute path because they are packaged with the application. But you can use an `AssetManager` object to get an `InputStream` on an asset.